# How do I fix these "illegal start of expression" errors?

Tags: java

i have been working on this code for school but i have been getting some errors that i cant fix.can someone help me!!!!. what the code does is a user input a number 1 2 3 or 4 in the text box and the Applet will draw out a different shape for each number.

```
the errors
illegal start of expression - line 53
illegal start of expression - line 53
';' expected - 53
';' expected - 53
illegal start of expression - line 63
illegal start of expression - line 63
';' expected - 63
';' expected - 63






/**
* @(#)fourshapesACON.java
*
* fourshapesACON Applet application
*
* @
* @version 1.00 2011/3/28
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class fourshapesACON extends Applet
{

Container pane = getContentPane();

JLabel question = new JLabel("pick one of the four shapes:1-Cirle, 2-Square, 3-Rectangle, 4-Oval");

JLabel choice1 = new JLabel("Circle");

JLabel choice2 = new JLabel("Square");

JLabel choice3 = new JLabel("Rectangle");

JLabel choice4 = new JLabel("Oval");

JLabel other = new JLabel("the number you have pick didn't match. pick from the numbers given");

JTextField answer = new JTextField(20);

JButton hey = new JButton(Enter);

public void init()
{

pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

pane.add(question);

pane.add(choice1);

pane.add(choice2);

pane.add(choice3);

pane.add(choice4);

pane.add(other);

pane.add(anwser);

pane.add(hey);

pane.add(Enter);

hey.addActionListener(this);

pane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

question.setforeground(Color.WHITE);

choice1.setforeground(Color.GREEN);

choice2.setforeground(Color.GREEN);

choice3.setforeground(Color.GREEN);

choice4.setforeground(Color.GREEN);

other.setforeground(Color.RED);


public void actionPeformed(ActionEvent e)***(this is line 53)***
{

String reply = answer.getText();

String choice1="1";

String choice2="2";

String choice3="3";

String choice4="4";


public void paint(Graphics g)***(this is line 63)***
{


if (reply.equals(choice1)) {

pane.add(choice1);

g.drawRoundRect(200,200,80,80);


} else if (reply.equals(choice2)){

pane.add(choice2);

g.drawfillRect(200,200,80,80);


} else if(reply.equals(choice3)) {

pane.add(choice3);

g.drawfillRect(200,200,80,40);


} else if (reply.equals(choice4)){

pane.add(choice4);

g.drawfillOval(200,200,50,50);

} else
pane.add(other);


}

}

}

}
```

Comment: This is not how one asks questions on SO, which is why your question is about to be closed as "not a real question".  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: That's not very specific, Jim.  I actually thought that he did a good job identifying the errors he received and marking the code line numbers the errors were on.  I was working on a pretty good answer when you closed it.  Too bad I can't help this guy.  I'm nominating for reopening.

Comment: If you had closed it as a duplicate to this question, I might have understood: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534263/how-do-i-fix-an-illegal-start-of-expression-error-in-java

Answer (score 1):

why method **paint** is defined inside **actionPeformed**?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a closing `;` after `other.setforeground(Color.RED)` (and you've also done this before the definition of paint).  When you see an error, try looking at the preceding lines too as that'll often given you a hint about what has gone wrong.